Definition of the integral of a continuous function over a compact set when you only defined the integral for compactly supported functions
Let $h\ge 0$ be a continuous function defined on an open set $V\subset \mathbb{R^n}$.
The integral of $h$ over a compact set $K \subset V$ can be defined as $$\int_K h(x)\,dx = \inf_{\substack{f \in C_c(\mathbb{R^n}) \\ f\ge \mathbb{1}_K}} \int_{\mathbb{R^n}}f(x)h(x)\,dx$$
, where $1_K$ is the characteristic function of the set $K$. Using this definition one can prove that the integral over a compact set like $Q:=[a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times[a_n,b_n]$ for an arbitrary continuous function $g\in C(\mathbb{R^n})$ is $$\int_Q g(x)\,dx = \int_{a_1}^{b_1}\cdots\int_{a_n}^{b_n}g(x_1,\dots,x_n)\,dx_n\cdots dx_1$$
Is this easy to see?

Depends on what you’re willing to assume. A possibility is to write the complement $K^c$ as a countable increasing union of closed sets $C_n$ with compact complement in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then for every $n$ to use Tietze’s theorem to separate $K, C_n$ by a continuous function $f_n$ which takes values in $[0,1]$, assigns $0$ to $C_n$ and $1$ to $K$.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

@UriGeorgePeterzil - as compact sets in $\Bbb R^n$ are closed and $\Bbb R^n$ is connected, the only closed set in $\Bbb R^n$ with compact complement is $\Bbb R^n$ itself.
